# Magento2 - How to get order id in 'sales_order_invoice_pay' observer?

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice

Here I want to generate a Custom Invoice with Custom data and format right after default invoice generation.

So I have added an observer `sales_order_invoice_pay`. here I want to get Order Id but I have no idea how can I get order id in this observer.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$orderId = $order->getId(); //returning NULL

$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();//returning NULL
```

How can I get order id in this observer?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice */
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
$incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: Thanks allot i was searching from yesterday.

Comment: Can you help in my other problem also??

Comment: Which one @SayyedHasan

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310371/how-can-i-create-invoice-with-custom-format-and-default-invoice-generated-in-mag
plz see this and help me if you have any idea